# IIS Application Initialization doAppInitAfterRestart

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have Application Initialization module installed on IIS 7.5, configured apppool to be `AlwaysRunning` and site with `preloadEnabled`. This module works on apppool restart. When I change web.config of site, request from module is not sent. I have tried setting `doAppInitAfterRestart` to `true` but it didn't help. Is there a way to configure Application Initialization somehow to send request after appdomain restart (e.g. web.config changes)?

Comment: I am having same issue on IIS 10. Have you ever figured this out?

Comment: It seems that app init module is not integrated with asp.net and it is bug by design.

Answer (score 2):

I have had some limited success with the following:

After you change `doAppInitAfterRestart` to `true` in your application's `system.webServer/applicationInitialization` section, go to that same spot in the *Configuration Editor* and click on the ellipsis `...` button next to `(Collection)`.  A window will pop up.  Click the *Add* link, and enter the following:

```
hostName: thehosturlofyourapp.com
initializationPage: /thepageyouwanttoloadonrestart.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing Web.config does not force Application Pool to recycle, it only forces AppDomain restart https://www.treeloop.com/blog/iis-application-domain-and-pool-recycling and Application Initialization module does not work with AppDomain which is .Net specific concept